# How to fit discrete values into a normal distribution and then generate random samples?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

Let's say I have a variable x that can take the values in this list: [1,2,3,4,5]. I want to fit this range of [1,2,3,4,5] in a normal distribution function with mean 3 and some std dev.

I then want to generate 500 samples of x that fit that exact distribution - but ONLY comprising of these 5 discrete values - 1,2,3,4,5. So the final output would be a 500 length list comprising of just 1,2,3,4,5 but fitting the normal distribution defined above.

I've tried looking for a way to address this but am unable to find help around discretizing a continuous normal function as such?

Comment: Well, a normal distribution can have any (integer or noninteger) real value. So what you're describing isn't a normal distribution. It sounds like you want a discrete distribution with, say, p(5) = p(1), p(4) = p(2), and p(3) > p(2) > p(1). So with those constraints, you can pick p(1), p(2), and p(3), get p(4) and p(5) from that, and then use a Scipy or Numpy function to sample from a discrete distribution (I forget what the function is called, I'm sure you can find it).

Comment: I think you are looking for something like a [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Comment: @Robert Dodier `rv_discrete(values=(xk, pk))`